# Django when I ran server(manage.py) nothing shows up?

Tags: django

I am working on Django web framework , Its been almost one year.

Today I ran into strange problem. when I run my manage.py runserver command on Django and try to see result in browser nothings shows up page is blank. Till yesterday it was fine. I am absolutely blank what to do.I though Due to Java script problem but even 127.0.0.1:8000/admin page is not showing.

I tried to change the port number ,used private browsing mode on browser both firefox and chrome still it shows nothing.

What is the problme? I tired to google it sstill I couldnot find solution of my problme. Need your help.

Thanks

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Console doesnt show anything..

Comment: Please copy/paste what your terminal (console) shows when you do `manage.py runserver`

Comment: Hello, Now it is working fine today...I dont knw waht was the problem but today it is working fine.I didnot do anything.